# How to call a function after switch statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a form. Which has a selector with 9 options, all similar but different to each other.

I am calling `calcTotal()` function after every change in the select. `calcTotal` has a switch statement with 9 cases. I think I am not calling the `calcTotal` function correctly. Because after I select an option, the `adultTotal` and `childTotal` are not updating as assigned, instead they are showing their values as "undefined".

How do I call a function after every select? (I have 4 in this case, "typeSel", "c1bed", "c2bed", "c3bed")

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#typeSel').on('change', function () {
        switch (this.value) {
            case '1': {
                $("#a1det").show();
                $("#cdet,#a2det,#a3det,#a4det").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#adult1").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#cdet :input,#childr :input,#a2det :input,#a3det :input,#a4det :input,#adult2,#adult3,#adult4").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "1";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "1";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "0";
                booktype = 1;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }

            case '2': {
                $("#a1det, #a2det").show();
                $("#cdet,#a3det,#a4det").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#a2det :input,#adult2").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#cdet :input,#childr :input,#a3det :input,#a4det :input,#adult3,#adult4").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "2";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "2";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "0";
                booktype = 2;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }

            case '3': {
                $("#a1det, #a2det, #a3det").show();
                $("#cdet,#a4det").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#a2det :input,#a3det :input,#adult1,#adult2,#adult3").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#cdet :input,#childr :input,#a4det :input,#adult4").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "3";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "3";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "0";
                booktype = 3;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }

            case '4': {
                $("#a1det, #a2det, #a3det, #a4det").show();
                $("#cdet").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#a2det :input,#a3det :input,#a4det :input,#adult1,#adult2,#adult3,#adult4").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#cdet :input,#childr :input").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "4";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "4";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "0";
                booktype = 4;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }

            case '5': {
                $("#a1det, #a2det, #cdet, #c1det").show();
                $("#a3det,#a4det,#c2det,#c3det").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#a2det :input,#c1det :input, #child1,#adult1,#adult2,#childTotal").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#child2,#child3,#adult3,#adult4,#a3det :input,#a4det :input,#c2det :input,#c3det :input").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "5";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "2";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "1";
                booktype = 5;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }

            case '6': {
                $("#a1det, #a2det, #cdet, #c1det, #c2det").show();
                $("#a3det,#a4det,#c3det").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#a2det :input,#c1det :input,#c2det :input,#adult1,#adult2,#child1,#child2,#childTotal").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#child3,#adult3,#adult4,#a3det :input,#a4det :input,#c3det :input").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "6";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "2";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "2";
                booktype = 6;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }

            case '7': {
                $("#a1det, #a2det, #cdet, #c1det, #c2det, #c3det").show();
                $("#a3det,#a4det").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#a2det :input,#c1det :input,#c2det :input,#c3det :input,#adult1,#adult2,#child1,#child2,#child3,#childTotal").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#adult3,#adult4,#a3det :input,#a4det :input").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "7";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "2";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "3";
                booktype = 7;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }

            case '8': {
                $("#a1det, #a2det, #a3det, #cdet, #c1det").show();
                $("#a4det,#c2det,#c3det").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#a2det :input,#a3det :input,#c1det :input, #child1,#adult1,#adult2,#adult3,#childTotal").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#child2,#child3,#adult4,#a4det :input,#c2det :input,#c3det :input").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "8";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "3";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "1";
                booktype = 8;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }

            case '9': {
                $("#a1det, #a2det, #a3det, #cdet, #c1det, #c2det").show();
                $("#a4det,#c3det").hide();
                $("#a1det :input,#a2det :input,#a3det :input,#c1det :input,#c2det :input,#child1,#child2,#adult1,#adult2,#adult3,#childTotal").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#child3,#adult4,#a4det :input,#c3det :input").attr("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById("booktype").value = "9";
                document.getElementById("adultNum").value = "3";
                document.getElementById("childNum").value = "2";
                booktype = 9;
                return booktype;
                break;
            }
        }
        return booktype;
        calcTotal();
    });

    $('#c1bed').on('change', function () {
        switch (this.value) {
            case 'a': {
                child1 = childa;
                break;
            }
            case 'b': {
                child1 = childb;
                break;
            }
            case 'c': {
                child1 = childc;
                break;
            }
            case 'd': {
                child1 = childd;
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("child1").value = child1;
        calcTotal();
        return child1;
    });

    $('#c2bed').on('change', function () {
        switch (this.value) {
            case 'a': {
                child2 = childa;
                break;
            }
            case 'b': {
                child2 = childb;
                break;
            }
            case 'c': {
                child2 = childc;
                break;
            }
            case 'd': {
                child2 = childd;
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("child2").value = child2;
        calcTotal();
        return child2;
    });

    $('#c3bed').on('change', function () {
        switch (this.value) {
            case 'a': {
                child3 = childa;
                break;
            }
            case 'b': {
                child3 = childb;
                break;
            }
            case 'c': {
                child3 = childc;
                break;
            }
            case 'd': {
                child3 = childd;
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("child3").value = child3;
        calcTotal();
        return child3;
    });
});

function calcTotal() {
    switch (booktype) {
        case '1': {
            adultTotal = adult1;
            childTotal = 0;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
        case '2': {
            adultTotal = +adult1 + +adult2;
            childTotal = 0;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
        case '3': {
            adultTotal = +adult1 + +adult2 + +adult3;
            childTotal = 0;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
        case '4': {
            adultTotal = +adult1 + +adult2 + +adult3 + +adult4;
            childTotal = 0;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
        case '5': {
            adultTotal = +adult1 + +adult2;
            childTotal = +child1;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
        case '6': {
            adultTotal = +adult1 + +adult2;
            childTotal = +child1 + +child2;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
        case '7': {
            adultTotal = +adult1 + +adult2;
            childTotal = +child1 + +child2 + +child3;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
        case '8': {
            adultTotal = +adult1 + +adult2 + +adult3;
            childTotal = +child1;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
        case '9': {
            adultTotal = +adult1 + +adult2 + +adult3;
            childTotal = +child1 + +child2;
            document.getElementById("adultTotal").value = adultTotal;
            document.getElementById("childTotal").value = childTotal;
            break;
        }
    }
    totalFare = +adultTotal + +childTotal;
    document.getElementById("totalFare").value = totalFare;
}
```

Comment: Is that your actual logic? I ask as the first `switch` is completely redundant, just use `return this.value` - in fact all of your switch statements seem pretty redundant. What exactly is this code supposed to be doing? It would help to see a working example, or at the very least you HTML.

Comment: The first switch statement has some other statements inside each case, which I have hidden for now to reduce the code.

Comment: Please show your actual code. This reduced sample makes very little sense and seems to just raise more questions.

Comment: I've updated the code now.

Comment: You should really research the DRY principle.

Comment: Sure. I'll learn it. But for now I really need to get the calcTotal to run.

Comment: @Roman has your answer, you need to amend your logic so that you don't exit the function (through calling `return`) before you call `calcTotal()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152820/discussion-between-nitin-jain-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 2):

I focus only on the first switch because your code is realy messy and hard to follow..

## Explanation

Your `calcTotal()` has to be *befor* the `return`. The return statment will jump out of the function and nothing under it will be execute.

## Code

Your `switch` is very redundant. What you want to do is simply return your `value` as a `number`. That can you achieve with `Number(this.value)`.  Befor your return you have to call `calcTotal()`.

```
$('#typeSel').on('change', function() {
    calcTotal();
    return Number(this.value);
});
```

Comment: I actually have some other stuff on the switch statement which I had hidden to reduce the code. I've updated it and calling the function before returning the value didn't work.